# Ampps first run errors. Control panel blank

Tags: software-installation, lamp

```
[Ampps::exec] "/usr/local/ampps/apache/bin/httpd-k start" 
X Error: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied) 10
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 1 (X_ShmAttach)
  Resource id:  0x168
X Error: BadShmSeg (invalid shared segment parameter) 128
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 5 (X_ShmCreatePixmap)
  Resource id:  0x4400010
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x4400011
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x4400011
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x4400011
```

The previous error I experienced after a fresh install. Please do let me know if you have had the same issue and how you alleviated it.

Answer (score 4):

There are two way first
to run Ampps every time you need to run this command

```
sudo QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 /usr/local/ampps/Ampps
```

It will start Ampps application without any errors.

Permanent solution is to add the below command

```
export QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1
```

to `/etc/environment` file as this is your setting environment variable for Ubuntu OS.

Comment: This worked! But why is this necessary? What does this do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cd /usr/local/ampps/Ampps
```

then :

```
export QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1
```

then:

```
./Ampps
```